# Using variables in $in

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a request variable defined and for some reason I cannot use it in the $in block:

```js
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'users',
    as: 'user',
    let: {
      "blogIds": "$blog.id"
    },
    pipeline: [{
        $project: {
          id: 1,
          user_name: 1,
          picture: 1,
          blogs: 1
        },
      },
      {
        $match: {
          blogs: {
            $in: ["$$blogIds"]
          }
        }
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

if i try to send without `$match`, but with `$addFields:

```js
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'users',
    as: 'user',
    let: {
      "blogIds": "$blog.id"
    },
    pipeline: [{
        $project: {
          id: 1,
          user_name: 1,
          picture: 1,
          blogs: 1
        },
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          field: "$$blogIds"
        }
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Document example:

[image]

lorem ipsum dolor amen.

Comment: How did you try to use the property?

Comment: @Teemu, I sent the property with `$addFields`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use internal fields as input of another internal field,

There is a other way expression `$expr` operator to handle this situation,
`$expr` can build query expressions that compare fields from the same document in a `$match` stage.

```
{ $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$$blogIds", "$blogs"] } } }
```

Comment: it's weird, however it didn't help me anyway

Comment: please post some sample/example document in your question.

Comment: still didn't help

Comment: what is you expectation can you explain more in your quesiton.

Comment: Please tell me what you can clarify in the question?

Comment: from your question *some reason I cannot use it in the $in block:* i have resolve your incorrect syntax of $in. i can not see any other problem in your question.